# Computing $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure with Euclidean $n$-balls

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I am studying the coarea formula proof from Evans and Gariepy's *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*. At the start of lemma 3.5, the authors are assuming that we can compute the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure from coverings of closed balls, namely, that the Lebesgue measure of a measurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ equals
$$\text{inf}\left\{\left.\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathcal L^n(B_i)\,\right|A\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i,\,B_i\text{ closed ball in }\mathbb R^n\,\right\}$$

I don't think this assumption is obvious at all. I have searched for a while and I have not encountered yet a justification for this. [In the only answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287321/lebesgue-outer-measure-with-open-balls), some corollary of the Vitali covering lemma is applied. However, no-one can guarantee that the disjoint closed balls that approximate the rectangles of any covering of $A$ are going to contain, in their union, the set $A$ we are interested in...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Does the reader at this point know that Lebesgue measure and Haudsorff measure coincide?

Comment: Yes, and also Vitali covering theorem is available...

Comment: A priori I wanted an elementary proof of the fact, but propbably the Hausdorff measure approach might be smarter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula
$$\mathcal L^n(A)=\text{inf}\left\{\left.\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathcal L^n(B_i)\,\right|A\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i,\,B_i\text{ closed ball in }\mathbb R^n\,\right\}$$
can be proved as follows. Note only the inequality $\ge$ needs to be proved.
From the construction of product measure, we know that $A$ has a cover by boxes $R_i$ of total measure at most $\mathcal L^n(A)+\epsilon \,.$

As noted in [Gerald Edgar's answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287321/lebesgue-outer-measure-with-open-balls), the Vitali covering lemma yields  that for each  box $R_i$, there exist disjoint balls $B_{i1}, B_{i2}, \dots$ and a Lebesgue-null set $N_i$ so that
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_{ik} \subseteq R_i \subseteq N_i \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_{ik} .
$$
A box can be covered by cubes of  total measure at most twice the measure of the box. Therefore the null-set $N:=\cup_i N_i$ can be covered by cubes $Q_j$ of total measure at most $\epsilon$. for each cube $Q_j$, the smallest ball $B_j$ containing it has volume at most $C_n \mathcal L^n(Q_j),$ where $C_n$ just depends on the dimension $n$.
Combining $\{B_j\}_{j \ge 1}$ with the balls $\{B_{ik}\}$ discussed earlier gives a cover of $A$ by balls of total  volume at most  $\mathcal L^n(A)+(1+C_n)\epsilon \,.$

Comment: Sorry, $d$ was a typo, I usually use $d$ for dimension rather than $n$. I have now corrected this, let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Allright, your answer seems to be completely satisfactory. Thanks.

Comment: I think one explaination is required. You say that only the $\geq$ part needs to be proved. However, the covering by closed balls has a total volume of $\mathcal L^n(A)+(1+C_n)\varepsilon>\mathcal L^n(A)+\varepsilon=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathcal L^n(R_i)$. It seems that you are proving quite the opposite inequality...

Comment: Well, I guess what you really are doing is to construct a cover by closed balls whose total measure is arbitrarily close to the measure of the original set, and that suffices to prove the equality